# CSS class working on one page, but not another

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am trying to shift text down, in the head I am using the CSS:

```
<style>
   .movedown {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 20em;
   }
</style>
```

And the text I want moved down has the code:

```
<div class="movedown">......</div>
```

The first page I tried this on, it worked, but on the second one it's doing nothing.

Also, the opening `<style>` tag is not turning blue in notepad++ on the broken page, if that is something to do with it?

Comment: Can you please paste the code directly from notepad ++ of both of the apges?

Comment: Without any source code we can't help you. Use pastebin/jsfiddle/etc. or if you can create a small example that still shows your problem, you can post the code in your question. Until then, we can only guess.

Comment: You should show us more of the code as there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ please..

Comment: Look for unclosed quotes "" or " or '

Comment: Can you show the code before the style tags as well? Also, can you copy & paste the code from page 1 as well as page 2 for us?    It sounds like there could be an issue with quotation marks in the code before the styles but I cannot tell for sure with out the rest of the code

Comment: Problem between chair and keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

What I did was move the code that was in the head into the top of the body.
I don't know why it didn't work in the head but now it all works fine.

Comment: It _should_ work inside the head section. The problem was elsewhere.